# Links between pages in quarto website with qmd files in different subfolders

Tags: hyperlink, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc, quarto

I am creating a website with quarto (using RStudio). I want to have links between pages on my site, which usually works as described [here in the quarto documentation](https://quarto.org/docs/websites/#linking). However, I have saved the `.qmd` files for my pages within separate subfolders within the project directory as shown in this example `_quarto.yml`:

```yaml
website:
  title: "Main Title"
  navbar:
    title: "Navbar Title"
    left:
      - text: Pages
        menu:
          - text: Page A
            href: folderA/pageA.qmd
          - text: Page B
            href: folderB/pageB.qmd
```

When trying to add `[link](folderB/pageB.qmd)` anywhere within the `pageA.qmd` document, it incorrectly creates the link as `folderA/folderB/pageB.qmd` which obviously does not work.

How do I correctly assign links between pages in this setting?

Comment: Check out the the R package [`here`](https://here.r-lib.org/), which you can use to create paths relative to project root directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit tedious but you should be able to use relative paths, i.e. `..` to move to previous directory.

So in your case that would be `[Link](../folderB/pageB.qmd)`. Not a great solution but as long as your directory structure stays the same, it should work.

If you later on find yourself changing the structure you can use aliases to keep the old links alive.

Comment: Thanks! Seems so obvious now. (┛ಠ_ಠ)┛彡┻━┻